# Quality documentation for source code in c# project?

Tags: c#, code-documentation

I'm working with web API project  which contain layers (API, Domain, Repository, DTO, Entities). I want to document my source code for each layers.
I have started to comment each function for each layer. Is it a good way?
Which is the best technique or tools to create  and maintain accurate, professional quality documentation for my source code (c# project).

Answer (score 2):

Best is indeed to write summaries for all methods/classes in your code in xml format, like this:

```
/// <summary>  
///  This class performs an important function.  
/// </summary>  
public class MyClass{}
```

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/xml-documentation-comments

When using these xml based comments, you can also use different tools for generating a full documentation. Personally I've used [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/). It's a tool that generates a full HTML documentation based on the comments and summaries in your code.